# applications getting disappeared after minimizing them in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, appmenu

Just now I downloaded Zend studio and opened it. After some time I minimised it and I do not see it anywhere. If I try to reopen it, it will show that it is already been open and in use.

How to see where the minimized application is running?

Comment: did you installed compiz?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: No I have not installed compiz. Should I install it? Is it better

Comment: install compiz and then press alt+tab.

Answer (score 0):

Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` by running below commands on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

After the installation is completed,press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to see and reopen the minimized applications.